# React: Rerender component only when there has been a change in value

Tags: reactjs

I've run into a bit of a problem. 
This is my first react project an is suppose to be my version of watch2gether. 
I already have an API that let's me manage the rooms and users giving me json objects as response. 
Now my problem is that I would like to rerender my Lists for users, rooms, playlist,... not every few milliseconds but only when the data from my fetch request is diffrent from the data i already know of.
I'm already aware of useEffect() and it's second parameter to only change when the param in said array change but i can't get it to work quite like i want to.

```
function App() {
  var [userlist, changeUserlist] = useState()
  

  useEffect(()=>{
    getAllUsers()
    .then(data => changeUserlist(data))
    
  }, [])
```

idealy i would just put in [userlist] but that leaves me an endless loop of course.
I also tried to sperate my data from the response object so i could maybe save it as reference or do an if() then{} but ran into a wall with that too.

Everyone that could help me to find a way to keep everything up to date is greatly appreciated.

Edit1: getAllUsers()

```
async function getAllUsers () {
 
    return await fetch(fetchUrl +'users/')
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.status)
        if (!res.ok){
            throw Error('Failed to fetch')
        } 
        
        return res.json()
        
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        return err
    })
    
}
```

Response:
[the response obj of getAllUsers()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ir0C5.png)

Comment: "> different from the data i already know of."
How do you know ? have you saved it somewhere ?

Comment: from my understanding it should be saved in userlist.
i thought userlist from the useState() would be empty. 
the fetch would be executed and bc the fetch data is diffrent from userlist, user list saves the new data, rerenders and compares it so with the new fetch

Comment: Hi, Please post a sample of the `getAllUsers` api response data. It'll help to understand & answer your question.

Comment: Judging by `getAllUsers()` the only way you would notice some change would be by calling this method every few (milli-)seconds and compare its result with your `userList` state.

Comment: @NiceBooks i added a picture

Comment: @sm3sher im also open to new solutions if there is a better/best practice solution

Comment: Do you need to keep fetching from `getAllUsers` infinitely ie long-polling ?

Comment: @NiceBooks well technically i wouldn't need to keep the this specific userlist up to date since it only has a visual function but it will also serve as an example for the userlist within a room, the list of rooms people can join and potently more components that i would like to keep fairly recent. 
For now i have a solution that fetches every X seconds using setInterval in an useEffect hook, only getting the information from my userlist proves as a problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a param into the brackets, and when that param changes, React will rerender.

```
function App() {
  var [userlist, changeUserlist] = useState()
  

  useEffect(()=>{
    getAllUsers()
    .then(data => changeUserlist(data))
    
  }, [**param**])
```

Comment: i already tried that with param = [userlist] which ended in the infinite loop.
My current best option to my knowledge is letting one second pass and then fetching a new request/rerender.
Otherwise i dont know any better param than userlist to put to achieve my goal

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution: fetching every minute.

```
class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {userList: [], interval: null};
    }

    async updateUsers() {
        let userList = await getAllUsers();
        this.setState({userList});
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        await updateUsers();
        let interval = setInterval(updateUsers, 1000);     
        this.setState({interval});
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.state.interval);
    }
}
```